# Перестает собираться проект при добавлении using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client

Tags: .net, visual-studio, azure

1. Создаю проект Azure Func (2.х)
2. Создаю в нем функцию с триггером от очереди - ок
3. Добавляю привязку к CosmosDB (nuget пакет Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB) - ок
4. Добавляю `using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client` - проект перестает собираться.

Ошибка:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл."

Код в соответствии с примером с сайта Microsoft. Но сборка ломается в момент добавления требуемой для `DocumentClient` строки using.
В чем причина, как побороть?

код:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;

namespace FunctionApp3
{
    public static class Function2
    {
        [FunctionName("Function2")]
        public static void Run(
            [QueueTrigger("myqueue-items", Connection = "QueueSett")]string myQueueItem,
            [CosmosDB(databaseName: "db", collectionName: "msg", ConnectionStringSetting = "db_DOCUMENTDB")] DocumentClient client,
            TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Уточнение**. Явное добавление пакета System.Runtime требуемой версии проблемы не решает. Приводит другой ошибке:

> Detected package downgrade: System.Runtime from 4.3.0 to 4.1.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
>    FunctionApp3 -> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB 3.0.0-beta7 -> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions 3.0.0-beta5 -> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs 3.0.0-beta5 -> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core 3.0.0-beta5 -> System.Diagnostics.TraceSource 4.3.0 -> System.Runtime (>= 4.3.0) 
>    FunctionApp3 -> System.Runtime (>= 4.1.0)

Comment: Погляди в зависимостях эта библиотека лежит. Может он подтягивается автоматически.

Comment: @adrug не совсем понял, о чем речь. эта сборка всегда в зависимостях. чем мне это поможет?